# Convert JSON to YAML - getting error

Tags: ruby, json, yaml, open-uri

I am new to ruby and using formats like JSON and YAML. I am trying to convert the data I get from the StackEexchange API (JSON format) to YAML format.

This is the data I am trying to convert:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/html/top-answerers/month?site=stackoverflow

I saw some other posts here in StackOverflow and thought I'd first try to convert JSON to a hash then the hash to YAML. I tried the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
io = open('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/html/top-answerers/month?site=stackoverflow')
body = io.read[0, 100]
puts JSON.parse(body).to_yaml
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
/../ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 399: unexpected token at '{"has_synonyms":true,"is_moderator_only":false,"is_required":false,"count":284459,"name":"' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /home/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from a.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure if there is a **direct way to convert JSON to YAML**. If so please help me.

Comment: why are you doing `io.read[0,100]` ??

Comment: `io.read[0, 100]` i guess io is string and you have just cut it, so obviously it can't proper parse this. Or it is not?

Comment: Your `io.read[0,100]` is chopping off the JSON in the middle of something so your `body` is no longer JSON, it is just *part* of a JSON string.

Comment: ya probably. will check it ! thanks

Comment: sometimes, browsers will pretty print json and stip off the doublequotes which can cause missing token errors. ensure you are grabbing raw json source, then you can try a site like [www.json2yaml.com](http://www.json2yaml.com) before coding the request to make sure json is valid